# Loading shapefile into PostGIS: ${TRAINING_ROOT} Directory

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I try to follow this tutorial (link below: Loading shp file into PostGIS), however I dont understand how do I get to the $TRAINING_ROOT directory? It always tells me: No such file or directory.

https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/shp_postgis.html

Answer (score 2):

It's a shell variable - but in this context it just means replace `$TRAINING_ROOT` with where ever you unpacked the data.

Answer (score 2):

That is a GeoSolutions training package, which needs to be used along with training packages (data + software) that you can download from links at the bottom of this page (with a choice of Windows ZIP file or ISO/VM running Linux):

https://www.geosolutionsgroup.com/technologies/geoserver/

Once that is done, what Ian said, you'll have to replace the variable to the location where you unpacked the training. If you pick the Windows training, run `setenv.bat` to setup all variables, on the Linux one, I think they are already set, if not, there should be a `setenv.sh`.

Those training are done best with an instructor leading you, but they can also be done without with a bit of effort. Good luck!